# socket monitoring

Tags: java, sockets

How can I tell which java class is listening to a socket for a specific jvm in windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be either Socket or SocketChannel.  However, generally you will more interested in which thread is listening on a socket.  One way to find out is to use jstack to get a thread dump of the process.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the code then using reflexion and logging the name of the class through the class Class methods (yes, sounds redundant lol).